# How can one detect the OS type using Rust?

Tags: path, rust, cross-platform

How can one detect the OS type using Rust? I need to specify a default path specific to the OS. Should one use conditional compilation?

For example:

```
#[cfg(target_os = "macos")]
static DEFAULT_PATH: &str = "path2";
#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
static DEFAULT_PATH: &str = "path0";
#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
static DEFAULT_PATH: &str = "path1";
```

Comment: "*Should one use conditional compiling?*" — yes.

Comment: Depending on what kind of default path you need, there may be already a crate so _don't_ you need to write the `#[cfg]` yourself.

Answer (score 84):

It's a little late, but there's a builtin way to detect the OS using the std lib. Eg:

```rust
use std::env;

println!("{}", env::consts::OS); // Prints the current OS.
```

The possible values are described [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/consts/constant.OS.html)

Hope this help somebody in the future.

Answer (score 41):

You can also use `cfg!` syntax extension.

```
if cfg!(windows) {
    println!("this is windows");
} else if cfg!(unix) {
    println!("this is unix alike");
}
```

To just get `macos`, you can do:

```rust
if cfg!(target_os = "macos") {
  println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=framework=CoreFoundation");
}
```

Comment: This treats Linux, BSD, and OSX as the same platform. Sometimes this is what you want but not always.

Comment: @SeanPerry once you know it's a UNIX like system you can just check for files or commands that should tell you which system/distro/version you're running on.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT:

Since writing this answer, it seems the author of the `os_type` crate has retracted functionality that exposed OSes like Windows. Conditional compilation is probably your best bet here -- `os_type` only seems to detect Linux distributions now, judging from its [lib.rs](https://github.com/schultyy/os_type/blob/master/src/lib.rs).

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

You could always use the [`os_type`](https://github.com/schultyy/os_type) crate. From the front page:

```
extern crate os_type;

fn foo() {
      match os_type::current_platform() {
        os_type::OSType::OSX => /*Do something here*/,
        _ => None
    }
}
```