# How do I port code calling QueryPerformanceFrequency to Rust?

Tags: windows, time, rust

I need to port this C code into Rust:

```c
QueryPerformanceFrequency((unsigned long long int *) &frequency);
```

I didn't find a function that does that.

The Linux variant looks like:

```c
struct timespec now;
if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now) == 0)
    frequency = 1000000000;
```

Should I call `std::time::Instant::now()` and set the frequency to 1000000000?

This is the complete function:

```c
// Initializes hi-resolution MONOTONIC timer
static void InitTimer(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));              // Initialize random seed

    #if defined(_WIN32)
        QueryPerformanceFrequency((unsigned long long int *) &frequency);
    #endif

    #if defined(__linux__)
        struct timespec now;
        if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now) == 0)
            frequency = 1000000000;
    #endif

    #if defined(__APPLE__)
        mach_timebase_info_data_t timebase;
        mach_timebase_info(&timebase);
        frequency = (timebase.denom*1e9)/timebase.numer;
    #endif

    baseTime = GetTimeCount();      // Get MONOTONIC clock time offset
    startTime = GetCurrentTime();   // Get current time
}
```

Comment: *Should I [...] set the frequency to 1000000000?* — that's something that only you can decide. If it's OK to have bogus values, why not always use bogus values — it's probably faster to run.

Comment: i'm just porting it, if there's a more precise way to do it, why not do it that way? the author went for precise stuff with windows and apparently on linux there's just no way of doing that so he used that value.

Comment: Note that on Linux, `clock_gettime` always returns a value in seconds+nanoseconds, so it makes sense to set frequency to 1,000,000,000 (=1s/1ns). On Windows, `QueryPerformanceCounter` gives "counts", and you need to use `QueryPerformanceFrequency` to get the number of "counts" per second for conversion.

Comment: The `clock_gettime` call doesn't do anything particularly interesting unless `now` is used later, so I have to agree with Shepmaster: the context that makes both of these snippets make sense is buried in the rest of your program. It doesn't make sense to ask about both of them because they don't have the same behavior.

Comment: > It doesn't make sense to ask about both of them because they don't have the same behavior. That is why i asked the question: they didn't seem to have the same behavior to me. Thanks.

Comment: on https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime   it is said: clock_gettime(), clock_settime() and clock_getres() return 0 for success, or -1 for failure (in which case errno is set appropriately). so in all other cases it returns a value in seconds + nanoseconds?

Comment: @PaulFilipenco No, it either returns 0 or -1. You pass it `&now` so it has a place to store the result. That's why I said it doesn't do anything interesting unless you do something with `now`, because if it doesn't have an `else` clause or some other context you might as well just replace the whole snippet with `frequency = 1000000000;`. You've  probably snipped out too much, which is why it doesn't make sense. (Of course, it might also not make sense to begin with.)

Comment: @trentcl i added the context, thank you for the attention and help.

Comment: This function looks like it has at least one bug. What does the definition of `frequency` look like?

Comment: @trentcl [link to single header library](https://github.com/victorfisac/Physac/blob/master/src/physac.h), the definition looks like: `static uint64_t frequency = 0;`

Comment: And is `0` a reasonable value for `frequency` to have? Because if `clock_gettime` fails, it's never going to be set to anything else and the rest of your program will have to deal with the consequences of `frequency` being zero. If `clock_gettime` can't fail, there's no point in calling it at all, since you do nothing with the result. The Windows code presumably does something meaningful; the Linux code looks like it was originally meant to do something analogous, but now doesn't. Again, maybe there is some additional context that makes this function make sense, but it seems unlikely to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct solution to accessing Windows APIs is to use the `winapi` crate. In this case, call [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.8/winapi/um/profileapi/fn.QueryPerformanceFrequency.html):

```
use std::mem;
use winapi::um::profileapi::QueryPerformanceFrequency;

fn freq() -> u64 {
    unsafe {
        let mut freq = mem::zeroed();
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&mut freq);
        *freq.QuadPart() as u64
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

```
[dependencies]
winapi = { version = "0.3.8", features = ["profileapi"] }
```

---

> hi-resolution MONOTONIC timer

I would use [`Instant`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Instant.html) as a monotonic timer and assume it's high-enough precision until proven otherwise.

Comment: The original can be compiled on multiple platforms and i do want my solution to be universal, but i will search to see if i can do platform specific stuff in rust, thanks!

Comment: @PaulFilipenco [How can one detect the OS type using Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43292357/155423)

Comment: Thank you a lot!